# Can I run wayland application in X?

Tags: xorg, wayland

Is there's wayland server running as X11 client? Like [XWayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/xserver.html) but reversed.

Comment: So in case anybody is wondering why, it's drivers. Some video cards have only X11 drivers available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Weston, the reference compositor for Wayland, has a special feature where instead of running it directly on hardware, you can also use it to run Wayland clients under X. At an X terminal, type `weston` and press Enter.

From [man 1 weston](https://www.mankier.com/1/weston) with my emphasis:

> Weston has several backends as loadable modules: it can run on Linux KMS (kernel modesetting via DRM), **as an X client,** or inside another Wayland server instance.

Source: [Jan Newmarch. "Running Wayland". *Programming Wayland Clients*, chapter 5](https://jan.newmarch.name/Wayland/RunningWayland/#heading_toc_j_1). Found via Google Search for `wayland under x`.

> No, you don't type `westoff` to close it.

Comment: And here's how to run a applications in Weston's wayland session: set environment variable `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland`. For example, `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland gnome-terminal`.

Comment: [`kwinft`](https://gitlab.com/kwinft/kwinft) ("*[The KWinFT project is a reboot of KDE's KWin.](https://gitlab.com/kwinft/kwinft)*") also can do that.